# assigning parameters to a model in a link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, parameter-passing, link-to

if am trying to pass a parameter through a link and assign it to a specific model. here is the code i'm working with:

```
<%= link_to ( image_tag("item.png", :size => "50*50", :border=> 0, :alt => "item", :title => "item"), {:action => 'initialize_order', :frame_id => 1 }) %>
```

right now :frame_id is getting passed through as:

```
{"frame_id"=>"1"}
```

i want the parameter to be assigned to the model :order, returning:

```
"order"=>{"frame_id"=>"1"}
```

i know the answer must be simple but i've searched for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your url args:

```
{:action => 'initialize_order', :order => {:frame_id => 1 }}
```

alternatively, since you only have one parameter, just pass it as :id and assign it in the controller.

Even better, build your app using RESTful routes, with an orders_controller and an initialize method.  If orders and frames have a parent-child relationship, then nest them in your resources.  That way you can use all the path generators.

Comment: thanks - i thought i already tried that but it works perfectly. i have several different items that could be selected, sending in different parameters to the :order model so this is easy for me to understand right now.